# How to make an SRV record correctly?

Tags: srv-record

I have made A record for the domain mydomain.com and for sipservice.mydomain.com. I also made an SRV record. By checking the record with the command:

> host -t srv _sip._tcp.mydomain.com

I get this result:

```
_sip._tcp.mydomain.com has SRV record 0 5 8080 sipservice.mydomain.com.
```

But when I try to navigate  the domain in the browser without specifying the port to the site, the transition does not work.

What am I doing wrong? Or does it take some time to work?

Answer (score 2):

Creating the correct `SRV` record is only one part of the equation, to use one effectively you also need a client that utilises / supports them for a given service.

> navigate the domain in the browser without specifying the port

Webbrowsers generally do not support SRV records for connecting to a web server running on another port than 80 (for plain HTTP) or 443 (for HTTPS).

---

Also, talking about SIP, if I recall correctly, SIP uses UDP and not TCP and you would normally set up an `_sip._udp.example.com.` SRV-record.

Comment: *Recently* there appeared a [new RFC draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-dnsop-svcb-https/00/?include_text=1) for a kind of SRV-like records suitable for HTTP(S), which are called `SVCB` and `HTTPS`. Modern browsers seem to respect these.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov: It is sad how they are trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @EsaJokinen: That's true. I [already expressed](https://serverfault.com/questions/1093680/what-is-principial-difference-between-upcoming-dns-svcb-rrs-and-good-old-srv-rec) my concern. Not everybody agree with this. There was 14 types of DNS records, let's invent a new type to replace them all,.., now there's 15 types of DNS records.